# ASP.NET Core Deploying App Fails with Apache

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to learn ASP.NET Core it's really awesome so far :) 
I've installed the Core Runtime and everything else needed to run a WebApp,
what I'm struggling the last couple hours is,
that I only can access the WebApp when I use the Port in the URL like `http://ip:5000` but when I try it like this `http://ip/WebApp` I'm getting a 404 Error.

Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache

I'm pretty sure that I've configured everything in Apache to make it work. This is my conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/WebApp/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /WebApp http://localhost:5000
  ProxyPassReverse /WebApp http://localhost:5000
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and my little sample app

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
               .Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```

What am I missing here? I'm pretty sure that this is a noob question but bare in mind that I'm trying to learn :=)

Comment: Have you tried .UseUrls("http://*:WebApp") in your WebHostBuilder?

Comment: No I will try that , do I need to change it also in the conf file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but http://*.WebApp gives me a System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://*:webapp:80: :(

Comment: Sorry my mistake, without the semi colon. Try this, .UseUrls("http://*/WebApp"). And leave config as is.

Comment: Thanks but still the same exception System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://*:80/webapp: address already in use.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to **Fix** this issue by changing both the config and my code in the Main Method to:

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000/WebApp")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

    host.Run();
```

and in the Config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/WebApp
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /WebApp http://localhost:5000/WebApp
  ProxyPassReverse /WebApp http://localhost:5000/WebApp
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```